# How can I assign a Vehicle Routing Problem to visit orders multiple times?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, routing

I am developing a new set of routes for my organization facility inspectors to minimize travel time. I have used ArcMap's Network Analyst to solve this for seven routes (one for each day of the week), and it worked well. However, after presenting it to the end users, I learned that different facilities are on different inspection cycles- some are visited weekly, some daily, and some two, three, or four times per week.

Is there a way I can have my orders be revisited?

I've thought of copying those orders that need multiple visits and then assigning them to separate routes or providing them with different time-windows, but that would make the assignments arbitrary and defeat the point of the analysis.

I'm running ArcMap 10.2.2

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. I hadn't realized that time windows could have dates as well as times associated with them! For every additional visit to a stop I simply copy the point and give each copy a non-overlapping time-window.